# How to save many images as i single image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an application where users add several images to view as sub views to show a complete image. Now i want to show that complete image in other class's image view.How can i do it because that complete image is just an image over another image and not a full single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically get the complete image of what is displayed on view. Here is a link to show how to do that http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/27/1188/

and then you pass the image to your next controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImage.size);
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    [secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```